# Need help displaying specific text based on product price in woocommerce

Tags: php, function, woocommerce

This is what I have right now to make text display underneath the product price and information on the shop page:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'bbloomer_show_free_shipping_loop', 5 );
 
function bbloomer_show_free_shipping_loop() {
   echo '<p class="shop-badge">Orders over $99 ship FREE</p>';
}
```

And that's appearing correctly on the site.

However, I need a NEW message to appear that says "This product ships free" when a product is over $99. It needs to replace the "Orders over $99 ship FREE" that's there now if a product is over $99.

I think it's a simple function, but I can't find exactly what I need anywhere. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have access to the global `$product` variable in the hook, so you can simply retrieve its price and conditionally show the text, e.g.:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'bbloomer_show_free_shipping_loop', 5 );
function bbloomer_show_free_shipping_loop() {
  global $product;
  $product_price = $product->get_price();
  if ( $product_price > 99 ) {
    echo '<p class="shop-badge">This product ships free</p>';
  } else {
    echo '<p class="shop-badge">Orders over $99 ship FREE</p>';
  }
}
```